# Split in bytes with delimiters

Tags: python

I want to catch the delimiter **7E**, but I have a problem.

packet: **7E**0011B81123423B303B303B393**7E**8

If 1 byte is 2 characters it will look like this:
7E 00 11 B8 11 23 42 3B 30 3B 30 3B 39 37 E8

```
packet = b'7E0011B81123423B303B303B3937E8'
packet_res = packet.split(bytes(b'7E'))
print(packet_res)

>>> [b'', b'0011B81123423B303B303B393', b'8']
```

It's supposed to be one and as a result I have two.

Comment: what result are you expecting? `7E 00 11 B8 11 23 42 3B 30 3B 30 3B 39 37 E8`?

Comment: I want one packet, the delimiter is 7E. And here he sees two packets because the second 7E appears, but not in one byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon can try this:

```
packet = b'7E0011B81123423B303B303B3937E8'
if packet.decode('utf-8').startswith('7E'):
    print([x for x in re.split(r'(\w{2})', packet.decode('utf-8')) if x]) # first 
    print(' '.join([x for x in re.split(r'(\w{2})', packet.decode('utf-8')) if x])) #second
```

**output:**

```
['7E', '00', '11', 'B8', '11', '23', '42', '3B', '30', '3B', '30', '3B', '39', '37', 'E8'] #first

7E 00 11 B8 11 23 42 3B 30 3B 30 3B 39 37 E8 #second
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to regex:

```
import re
packet = b'7E0011B81123423B303B303B3937E8'
print(' '.join(re.findall('..',''.join(re.findall('(7E.*)7E',str(packet))))))
```